# VirtualBox And Genymotion launch from command line issue

Tags: macos, jenkins, virtualbox, tcpclient, genymotion

I have installed latests Genymotion version 2.4.0 and Virtual Box 4.3.26 r98988. 
When i run genymotion from Jenkins or command line on MacOSX Yosemite:

```
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name "Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920"
```

i have this issues:

```
Logging activities to file: .Genymobile/genymotion.log
Logging activities to file: .Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920/genymotion-player.log
OpenGL connected to 192.168.56.101:25000
Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
Unknown TCPCLI command 1003
```

Jenkins waits indefinitely and the calabash tests are not running.

Logs of genymotion have no particular errors, but virtualbox's log (VBoxSVC.log) have this error:

```
00:00:00.130196 nspr-2   HostDnsMonitorProxy::notify
00:00:00.130211 nspr-2   HostDnsMonitorProxy: Host's DNS information updated:
00:00:00.130214 nspr-2     server 1: 10.10.0.30
00:00:00.130217 nspr-2     server 2: 10.10.0.31
00:00:00.130221 nspr-2     no search string entries
00:00:00.130223 nspr-2     no domain set
00:00:00.134010 nspr-2   failed to create vboxnet0, error (0x80004005)
00:00:00.134189 nspr-2   VDInit finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try "--quiet" while running the player.
I have the same error "Unknown TCPCLI command 1003" but it still seems to work fine.
This is how I run mine.

File: run.sh

```
vboxmanage snapshot "Google Nexus S - 2.3.7 - API 10 - 480x800" restore "factory"
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --quiet --vm-name "Google   Nexus S - 2.3.7 - API 10 - 480x800" &
echo "going to sleep"
sleep 30
echo "wake up"
```

Comment: thank you for reply but don't work .... ok, jenkins do not expect more correct, but the emulator crash/freeze when loading android environment.

Comment: I clean all,and i created a new android virtual machine and now its work.